# How to express in LINQ, an SQL OrderBy clause over two fields

Tags: sql, linq, sql-order-by

I need to write the following SQL statement in **LINQ lambdas**:

```
SELECT *
FROM product
ORDER BY ProductScore DESC, ProductID ASC
```

I guess this code:

```
product.OrderByDescending(m => m.ProductScore).OrderBy(m => m.ProductId)
```

it is not equivalent since the second OrderBy will overwrite the first one. Is there any equivalent? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`ThenBy` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx):

```
var query = product.OrderByDescending(m => m.ProductScore)
                   .ThenBy(m => m.ProductId);
```

There's also a [`ThenByDescending` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534736.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you use [`ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535112.aspx):

```
product.OrderByDescending(m => m.ProductScore).ThenBy(m => m.ProductId)
```

(and likewise `ThenByDescending`). That's the `Queryable.ThenBy` link; there's an equivalent on `Enumerable` of course.

In a query expression, this would be:

```
var query = from product in db.Products
            orderby product.ProductScore descending, product.ProductId
            select product;
```

`ThenBy` and `ThenByDescending` can *only* be called on `IOrderedQueryable` / `IOrderedEnumerable`... see my [Edulinq blog post on this for more information](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/04/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-26a-iorderedenumerable.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.thenby.aspx):

```
var query = db.Products
              .OrderByDescending(m => m.ProductScore)
              .ThenBy(m => m.ProductId);
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
product.OrderByDescending(m => m.ProductScore).ThenBy(m => m.ProductId)
```